# Android - SharedPreferences vs Cloud

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, azure-mobile-services

This is not a question about code.

I'm developing a Android App with Microsoft Azure Mobile Services but I have some doubts about how should I manage the data in the client side.

For example, I'm working with Google Maps and I have a fragment with a list of dozens of points (latitude and longitude) to add markers on the map, but if I decide to load that points from Azure everytime I enter that fragment it takes a few seconds to load the data, and the same happens with some data to transform in listviews.

My question is, should I work as many times as possible with SharedPreferences, updating them everytime I call the server side to insert, update or delete something, or should I just use SharedPreferences to save a personal data like username, date of birth, email, etc, and call the server side to read other complex data from the user?

Comment: Yeah you should store it somewhere, but SharedPreferences is not supposed to be accessed so frequently. It's not really as performant as sqLite depening on the amount of data. You should consider the possibility of keeping the data in RAM only and pass it between activities (if size is not so big).

Comment: thanks, i'll consider those things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, It is better to **manage data** by reducing additional network
>   call. It will not only increase the performance of your app but also
>   will take care of user experience.

Depending on the complexity and volume of data and the frequency of changes, you have to take a decision. If all the changes can be loaded in a single network call then you can store those data into shared preference and manage the local changes from app and at the end of the session just sent the modification token to the remote cloud server. It will increase the performance of your application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll just wait a few minutes to see if there are more opinions about this and then mark this as correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You must try handle those situations, when user can't connect to the cloud, and fetch data. So you must store it locally, on the device. Also, extra internet connection reduce battery charge, so you must access cloud less frequently.

For better performance, the best options, is to save all those data into database, but if your data amount not so big, and SharePreferences speed not Influence at performance, you can use it to store this data.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually keep such data in an sqlite database for your application instead of unreliable `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: @wormwood87 it actually adds the database to the data/data folder inside the application's folder, so don't forget to encrypt it if you will use some sort of contact information and as far as I remember this is a good tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: I had never worked with sqlite before, I just watched a few tutorials from TheNewBoston a few minutes ago and it's easy, in a few minutes I already have a db for what I want. I'll put personal info in SharedPreferences and more complex data such as arraylists in the sqlite. Thanks again :D

Comment: @wormwood87 I am very glad to be of help, I felt relieved just like you when I first found out about sqlite :D thanks for the vote up and you can ask anything about it, if it's in my capability, I would be glad to help

Answer (score 0):

As an add-on to the good answers whether to cache/store locally or use a cloud db: If SharedPreferences are getting too small.

If you want to avoid the rather complex setup of a SQLite database (table setup, query definition, etc),  you can use either a NoSQL database like [SnappyDB](https://github.com/nhachicha/SnappyDB).

If you want to stick to SQL, you can make your life easier by using a [Object-relational-mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/).